# Gentoo default application for opening files

Tags: gentoo, file-management, freedesktop, mime-types

On my Gentoo box running without a desktop environment, every time I try to open a file the system tries to open it with Firefox. I understand that without a desktop environment "open file" cannot function correctly, but why is everything opened with Firefox? If I want to, can I change it to something else?

Comment: How are you trying to open the file? Under most unices, this is a per-application concept, not a generic OS concept.

Comment: @Gilles I tried in various ways: double-clicking from pcmanfm, clicking from the downloaded section of chromium, executing xdg-open. Firefox always comes up.

Comment: Chromium and xdg-open both use the FreeDesktop database. I don't know about pcmanfm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this information is handled in 2 places:

- Application .desktop files advertise what program can open
- MIME database which specifies what application should be used to open file with specific MIME

The MIME database can be customized by editing `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and `.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`. The tool which allows to edit it is `xdg-mime` from `x11-misc/xdg-utils`. **Please beware that man states it can be used only from inside desktop session**.

**Edit** Please note that some applications, like Firefox, do not respect the MIME database settings.

Comment: That's the FreeDesktop MIME database. Other applications might use the system database (`/etc/mailcap`, `~/.mailcap`); Firefox has its own proprietary database.

Comment: I know it under name of MIME database (sounds completely different then FreeDesktop MIME database). As Freedesktop is set of standards for X desktop environments I don't think I was wrong to present is as standard - and I did mentioned not all apps respect it.

Comment: Thanks for the right direction. The default application list is at `.local/share/applications/defaults.list` (which is also what `xdg-mime` edits).

Answer (score 0):

The command `file -i <filename>` might be useful for the cases when one does not know the specific mime type of a particular file. Once established it may be used as an input to `xdg-mime` utility to set the default open command.

dev-perl/File-MimeInfo ebuild constains `mimeopen` utility. It is a wrapper around the mentioned above commands.

Comment: To determined the mime type for xdg-mime you should probably use: `xdg-mime query filetype <file>`